# reusing backend modules in frontend

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

I have a simple express application, with a server module and some client code.

My application source files were originally organized in two directories (simplified):

```
│   package.json
│   readme.md
│
├───client
│       client.js
│       index.html
│
└───server
        server.js
        colors.js
```

The color module (`server/colors.js`) is, for the purpouse of this SO question, a commonjs module that exports a single value

```
 const color = "white";
 module.exports = { color };
```

`server/server.js` contains an express application that, among other things, uses the color defined in the module, and uses the `express.static` middleware to serve the files in the `client` directory.

```
 const color = require('./colors').color;
 ...
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , '..', 'client')));
```

The client code is inserted in the `<head>` of `index.html` as a module

```
<script defer src="client.js" type="module"></script>
```

So far so good, the server starts, serves from client directory all the client files mounted at its root route.

Now, I want to reuse the server colors module also from my client code.

So I create a new directory `shared` and I move the `colors.js` source file there.

```
│   package.json
│   readme.md
│
├───client
│       client.js
│       index.html
│
├───server
│       server.js
│
└───shared
        colors.js
```

Then, I change my `server.js` to import from the new location

```
  const color = require('../shared/colors').color;
```

and, to reuse it in the client, I add a virtual path in the server, mounting a new `express.static()` path

```
  app.use('/shared',express.static(path.join(__dirname , '..', 'shared')));
```

everything is good so far, the server requires the module, and serves both client and shared directories.

Now, to use the module in the client, I import `colors` in `client.js`

```
  import * as colors from './shared/colors.js';
```

but the browser throws an error  `ReferenceError: module is not defined`

How can I solve this error? or, what is the correct way, and best practice, if any, to reuse backend code from the frontend?

Comment: Be consistent about your module format, i.e. use ES6 module syntax with `export` everywhere? Alternatively, use one of the dozen solutions to convert between them.

Comment: Can't be consistent, maybe that is the problem. Both worlds must coexist. Can't use `export` in nodejs without converting  tons of `require`s and `module.exports` scattered over dozens of dependencies. Which is absurd. And at the same time, can't use `module.exports` in a couple of `import` modules in the frontend. So, my question might be rephrased to "how can mix both modes?"

Comment: Use a transpiler, or a module loader that supports the mix.

Comment: yep, it's my current approach, but it adds a step in the build process that interferes with the natural cycle of  immediate edit-inject-livereload-debug, and it impacts my productivity.

Comment: Most build tools and transpilers do support a watch mode, live reloading and source map debugging. But sorry, there is no other solution.